# Help with UNIX Crontab!

Tags: unix, cron

I want to shedule a task for 8.30am every Monday, for every month, for every year...

What would the UNIX Crontab format be?

Many thanks

O.

Comment: What server type/OS...

Weekdays can be different on crons for different systems..

Comment: How can this answer (2010) be a duplicate of a question that was asked after this one (2012)? This question is older

Answer (score 6):

You would put the crontab entry like this:

```
30 8 * * 1 COMMAND
```

The first field is minutes, the second is hours, and the fifth is days of the week (where Sunday is 0).

Comment: +1, Sunday can also be '7' on most systems.

Answer (score 1):

30 8 * * 1

See also 'man 5 crontab'

Answer (score 1):

```
#minute hour    mday    month   wday
30      8       *       *       1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
30 8 * * 1 <command>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was starting out with Linux/UNIX, I found something like [this](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jslibrary/demos/crontab.php) was quite useful.

I think [this one](http://crontab-generator.com/) is slightly easier to use.

Comment: I'm going with the "Teach a man to fish" analogy here, only teaching him to fish with Dynamite.

Answer (score 0):

You might find http://www.opsschool.org/en/latest/cron_101.html useful too. That's where I found http://cronchecker.net/ to verify my cron commands in plain english.